# Create REST API documentation via swagger.io

Tags: swagger

I have my REST API created with JAX-RS and Resteasy.  I annotated with swagger annotation and I would like to generate the documentation by running some task via the Eclipse maven plugin. (Eclipse Luna/Maven 3).
I included the following dependencies in the project .pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2-M2</version>
</dependency>
```

I create a new configuration under Eclipse -> Run Configuration with a Goal set to Package, but when I run it nothing happens. 
Am I missing some dependencies?

Can anyone suggest some tips, I am not making out in using this tool and the site documentation is not helping.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [swagger-samples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java) project, which shows how you need to configure your application after adding the annotations (which, I suggest you update to the latest, 1.5.7).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded the example but I can't get it working. I think I will try with http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/  instead.